# How is MCU Hulk voiced?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, thor-ragnarok, sound-effects

Starting in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hulk can remain calm enough for long enough to carry on semi-intelligent conversation.

Is the voice acting done by Mark Ruffalo? Is it digitally or acoustically altered?

Comment: How is MCU Hulk voiced? *Very carefully.*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: 

Comment: Mark Ruffalo: "Brilliantly, I like to think."

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   Yeah, I get the meme, but it really doesn't make sense to me in this context because *voicing* isn't something you can really do ***to*** someone unless you're talking about doing a performance to realize them.   And when you're performing them, you're acknowledging it's just a character so it can't take issue with the performance.  This isn't the same as if it were,say, "How is the Hulk conversed with?"  "Very carefully."  Then it makes sense.  What am I missing?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I’m using it out of context for vague comedic effect — although I’m sure that Mr Ruffalo, as a professional actor of some repute, does take great care over his vocalisations.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, alright then.  I just figured there was some deeper joke I wasn't getting for so many upvotes.  :)

Comment: Comedy is very subjective. Except for my jokes which are uniformly hilarious.

Answer (score 33):

According to Ruffalo, the entire acting piece (voice, facial motion capture and body motion capture) was done by him with no outside assistance.

> The Hulk. That's all me that's me and and the animation team all
>   working together but it's all I shot all. That's me acting, that's my
>   voice, that's my face and it's my body moving around

and this [video interview with Yahoo](https://uk.style.yahoo.com/mark-ruffalo-gave-hulk-new-voice-thor-ragnarok-165938911.html) goes over much the same ground

> **“When Hulk is speaking, that’s me,”** the actor says. “That’s me on the
>   day, in my motion capture suit, and **they’re capturing my voice.”**

---

The key to doing the "hulk voice" is to

> [pretend your throat is in your navel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtznSlhouZc)

---

You can see him doing some of the mo-cap in these clips

And hear him doing the voice on the red carpet at the film's premiere

Comment: Word from the actor is better than a third party source +1 :)

Comment: http://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/characters/Hulk/Hulk/ - Lou Ferrigno and Mark Ruffalo in Avengers, then just Mark Ruffalo in Age of Ultron and Thor Ragnarok.

Comment: Lou Ferrigno [voiced the Hulk in *Age of Ultron* and earlier MCU films](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Avengers-Age-Ultron-Bring-Back-Lou-Ferrigno-Hulk-Voice-42697.html). Also, [this article](http://deadline.com/2016/04/tessa-thompson-joins-the-marvel-universe-thor-ragnarok-1201735551/) says that Lou Ferrigno starred in *Thor: Ragnarok*, presumably as The Hulk.

Comment: @Thunderforge - That's incorrect. Ferrigno had a cameo appearance that was cut in editing#

Comment: @Thunderforge - You can him on set here (wearing what looks like an outfit) but he's not in any of these scenes where Loki is dressed like this; http://www.sanluisobispo.com/entertainment/movies-news-reviews/lvlwq6/picture182295536/alternates/FREE_1140/Tom%20and%20Lou

Comment: @Valorum I'd be interested to know more about if he was actually filmed or if he just visited the set for a day to observe the filming.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I've just looked at the credits and he's not in them. My gut instinct is that he was part of a crowd scene that got trimmed

Comment: `According to Ruffalo, the entire acting piece (voice, facial motion capture and body motion capture) was done by him with no outside assistance.` Yeah, Andy Serkis was rather busy at that time.

Answer (score 11):

## Mark Ruffalo

According to the following comicbook.com post.

> Up until now, every version of MCU Hulk has been voiced by Incredible Hulk '70s TV series icon, Lou Ferrigno; however, Ferrigno wasn't brought back for Thor: Ragnarok. So, who is the new voice Hulk? **Marvel fans will be proud to know that it's Bruce Banner himself, actor Mark Ruffalo!**
>   **For Thor: Ragnarok, Ruffalo took on all aspects of his character, playing Bruce Banner while doing both the motion-capture and vocal performances as The Hulk.** That means Thor: Ragnarok's Hulk is the most complete version of the character we've ever seen, and as stated in our official Thor: Ragnarok review, the difference really shows onscreen!
>   <sub>[comicbook.com, 'Thor: Ragnarok' - Who Is Hulk's New Voice?](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/11/02/thor-ragnarok-hulk-voice-mark-ruffalo/)</sub>

The [IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/fullcredits) for the cast of the film only shows Mark for the role of Hulk too for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Interestingly, Google cites Ferrigno as the voice of the Hulk in Age of Ultron, whereas IMDB gets it right. I've submitted a correction.

Comment: @Mwr247 I thought Ferrigno was the voice in Ultron?

Comment: Oops, meant Ragnarok >_< Weird